# Why the resource is created but the corresponding release cannot be found by helm list

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I have a chart that triggers the creation of the `Rancher store` through `jenkins`. I can find the corresponding resource through the `kubectl command` in the cluster, but I cannot find the corresponding release through the `helm list / helm list -a`. And this is not the first chart to have such a situation.

What could be the cause of this? I really appreciate any help with this

> helm version is 2.11

Comment: Did suggested solution work for you (updating version)?

Answer (score 1):

That might be due to changes in the **helm chart version**.

i would suggest changing the helm similar to you are running into the Jenkin and try helm list after that.

There are chances **helm 2** and **helm 3** not listing the old release due to version mismatch.